# Painting a white $4\times 4\times 4$ cube red twice

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

I found this problem in Chinese book of riddles. I'm sorry that I can't provide a reference for the book: it appears really old and the cover is blank.

> Using white cubes that measure $1\times 1\times 1$ make a cube that measures $4\times 4\times 4$ and paint its surface red. Then rearrange the same $1 \times 1 \times 1$ cubes into another white cube and again paint its surface red. Is it necessarily true that one can still make a white $4\times 4 \times 4$ cube from these smaller cubes?

I divided the $1\times 1\times 1$ cubes in four different groups: (1)interior, (2)face, (3)edge, (4)corner. So after the first iteration these cubes have 96 red surfaces, and after the second iteration 192 red surfaces, which leaves sufficiently many white faces to make one more white cube (if they are located properly). But I guess there's one more improper way, which will lead us to the solution (that there's a case where we cannot still make a white cube)?

Comment: Not interesting at all if you do not include any context, what have you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: First of all, I tried different ways of re-assembling with different ways of painting and in any case I've got a way to make it again. I didn't get closer to evidence that it's always possible, but I divided 1*1*1 cubes in 4 different groups like (1)inner, (2)on-wall, (3)edge, (4)angle. Sorry, but that's all I got. Tried to do my best for 2 days, but didn't solve it :(

Comment: The type of context you should add depends a bit on where did you find this problem? It could from a contest (there are a few signs pointing in that direction). If so, you should give us a link to the source. If this is from a book, then name the book. If it was assigned to you as a exercise, you should describe the course, pieces of theory covered recently OR your attempts, and why they failed.

Comment: anyway, changed the name :)

Comment: I did some improvements. Sorry, I'm new to this forum

Comment: Ok. Maybe I misunderstood your question. Are you asking is it _always_ possible to make a 4x4x4 white cube after the second round of painting, no matter how the cubes were re-assembled into a 4x4x4 white cube after the 1st round?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If there's a way to paint it red and then it would be impossible to re-asseble a white one than it is a complete solution.

Comment: It would be cool if you could at least include the title of the book. And welcome to MathSE! :) Would you mind if I edited your post for grammar, and to add the context you added in the comments?

Comment: Yes, of course! Thank you! Sorry, but book cover is blank. It's really the old one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call a piece a $C$-piece if it is a corner piece, $E$ for edge, $I$ for inside, and $F$ for face. We can force the pieces to land in the right spot so that the end result is a white cube.

Then for any $I$-piece, after painting the first time, and painting the second time, we can always make it into a $C$-piece. So, the path of an $I$-piece is from inside, to wherever, to a corner. Denote this as:

$$I \longrightarrow \star \longrightarrow C$$

The rest have similar properties, in fact,

$$\begin{align}
I &\longrightarrow \star \longrightarrow C \\
F &\longrightarrow \star \longrightarrow E \\
C &\longrightarrow \star \longrightarrow I \\
E &\longrightarrow \star \longrightarrow F \\
\end{align}
$$

Thus, given any painting, then rearrangement, and painting again, we can determine where the pieces should go to make a white cube.

Moreover, the cardinalities match up, so each map is bijection.